# How can I load code from another Dart package, known only at runtime?

Tags: dart

I am building a Dart application. It needs to load code from a third-party package, which is only known at runtime. My application needs to:

1. auto-discover the dependency
2. load a library from that dependency
3. interact with the dependency

Ideally, I do not want to require that my users specify the third-party dependency. The application should auto-discover the dependency.

For example, a workflow could be something like this:

1. User installs my app (`pub global activate my_app`)
2. User installs a "plugin" (`pub global activate plugin_for_my_app`)
3. User runs my app (`my_app`)
4. The app auto-discovers that `plugin_for_my_app` exists.
5. The app loads the plugin (via `spawnUri` perhaps?)
6. The app calls into the plugin

Requirements:

1. Must run from the command-line.
2. Must work on Windows, Mac, Linux.
3. Should (but doesn't have to) run when compiled to JavaScript.
4. `pub run` support is optional (`pub run` makes it tricky, because it rewrites your import URIs, so it's not a requirement)

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Lots of customers have asked me how to build apps that foster a third-party plugin ecosystem. Would love to get some patterns "on the record" to help authors "light up" their ecosystems. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use a transformer to scan the ~/.pub-cache/bin dir for dart files that import your package, and include them in your final script?

Comment: Stagehand could take advantage of a plugin system, yes. Stagehand does not yet have a plugin system, so we're open to suggestions.

Comment: @mezoni Yep, I understood the problem. What I suggest is, since pub install packages in the .pub-cache dir, a tranformer could be used to scan that dir for plugins

Comment: Well, I still think that locating and loading the plugin is the trickiest part. For interaction, the host app can just invoke the main function of the plugin, which already has access to its public API.

Answer (score 3):

This package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/plugins seems to do exactly what you want (haven't used it myself yet though) by loading plugins into isolates.

Comment: Thanks. I've asked the author to post an answer here.

Comment: This package is marked incompatible with dart2 :(

Answer (score 3):

In the plugins package, currently, there is no way to resolve dependencies through pub. When I originally designed the API it was assumed that the dependencies were already retrieved through `pub get`. With that said, plugin discovery on the file system is simple.

As you can see in the example in the README, loading plugins was as simple as `new PluginManager().loadAll(String directory)` which would automatically discover all plugins inside the directory and load them. This solution is ideal if all plugins are to be in one folder.

It is possible to do individual plugin directory loading as well, provided it follows the plugin directory structure. Using a `PluginLoader` you can load in a directory that contains the necessary files for a plugin to run properly. It is not necessary to call `load()` since the `PluginManager` will take care of calling in load for you.

### A simplified way of loading a plugin

1. Instantiate the `PluginManager`.

   `PluginManager pm = new PluginManager();`
2. Determine the plugin you want loaded. The plugins library will automatically
   determine the pub cache directory. As per the documentation of pub, the `PUB_CACHE` environment variable is also supported.
3. Load in the plugin. A `Future` is returned with a `Plugin` object that provides basic information about the plugin. The plugin requires a `pubspec.yaml` with a name, a packages directory, and a `bin/main.dart` source file. However we are loading from the pub cache, so we do not need to worry about the setup of the plugin, the only requirement is the package from the pub cache supports the plugins package.

```js
pm.loadFromCache("test-1.0.0").then((Plugin plugin) {
    print("Plugin loaded!");
    handle();
});
```

4. After all the plugins you desire to be loaded are initialized, the manager can now listen for requests properly. Simply use the listener to 'see' the incoming data.

### The plugin side

The plugin simply uses a receiver as provided by the `plugins` API.

```js
void main(List<String> args, SendPort port) {
    Receiver rec = new Receiver(port);
    rec.listen((Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) {
        print("Received data: $data");
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you share an example of loading plugins from the user's pub-cache? This may be sufficient.

Comment: Are you referring to `global_packages` or `hosted` in the pub cache? I'm working on an API hook that will enable easy access to the pub cache

Comment: The latest git version now has a hook to load from the pub cache, currently the name passed into `loadFromCache(String name)` must be precise: `loadFromCache("package-1.0.0")`

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your answer to include all the steps and code snippets required? We're looking for a canonical step-by-step answer.

Comment: There's still some work that needs to be handled. I need to expand on the pub cache API to ensure packages are there entirely.

Comment: I was able to add in support for hard dependencies from the pub server, I will work on it later to support transitive, git, hosted, and path dependencies. Transitive dependencies are high priority.

Comment: PluginManager is a class or package originating from where ? i cannot find it in the standard library, nor on pub.dev

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly answering the question (CL tools as requested), but I use `plugins` in the **browser** and wanted to share my "pattern".

My web application imports `includes.dart` which is a dynamically generated file that imports all `.dart` files found in a specified directory. The file gets (re-)generated at app startup by the backend, just before serving the files to the browser. The found `.dart` files implement a public api (eg. `init()` and `run()`) so that the main application can call their code. The `plugin` code are not loaded into separate isolates but are executed in the same isolate as the main app which gives the benefit of `plugins` sharing the same heap and you're able to access the `plugin` code directly. This solution also assumes the `plugins` resolve their own dependencies.

This setup works fairly well for my use case. However, as there's no real dynamic code reloading in  Dart (yet, I hope. see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10530), there's always a refresh step needed to load the new code.

Comment: The main app imports the plugin code at startup with `import "plugin1.dart"`  where `plugin1.dart` contains `class Plugin1 extends PluginApi {...}`. With that, you can call the plugin from the main with `plugin1Instance.run()`. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: That works only in pure Dart but not when you build it to JS this won't work, right?

Comment: Correct. This solution will not work as JS, only on Dart VM. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This will also not work when `dart2dart` is used for inlining dependencies, tree-shaking, and minification. (AFAIK dart2dart can't be used for Dart client side code yet). Basically this is only for a development setup. I used something like that when I played with a testrunner. Nice idea but very limited for deployment.

Comment: Also true. Haven't tested to get this working with `dart2dart` in a while but the last time I did, I didn't find a solution. However, I'm not limited to having to support all browsers and can use pure Dart. As you said, this is currently a "development" setup in terms of deployment but that's due to the Dart VM browser support or the lack of it. _Here's to hoping Dart VM will appear in Chrome one day._

Comment: I guess it should be possible to export a small API using dart-js-interop. This way it should be possible to call code from other Dart projects (again using dart-js-interop) loaded in the same page (even dynamically loaded projects) and even when built to JS. I haven't played with loading different Dart projects in the same page though, but I saw it mentioned that it works.

Comment: That might be possible but I personally haven't tested it. Will update the answer if I ever get there. That being said, this solution should work for CL tools as you are working in Dart VM.

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped the `plugins` package with a bit of sugar to provide some extra things like declarative RPC. It's very flexible, and samrg472 (the author of plugins.dart) is a good friend, so I have asked him to comment as well.

https://github.com/PolymorphicBot/PolymorphicBot/blob/master/lib/src/core/plugins/handler.dart